# Is there a way to return parsed data from the fetch API, rather than a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I am building an app that gets some data from an API using fetch and injects it into a web page. The app is structured in the model-view-controller pattern. I want to have the fetching and parsing of the data happen in the model and the injection into the website in the controller. However fetch returning a promise makes this rather tricky as it seems to leave me with the option to either do the parsing in the controller or the injection from the model, both of which I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to construct a function so it returns the data from fetch once it resolves, rather than the promise?

What I have now:

```
function showMessages() {
 fetch('https://example-api.com/messages')
   .then(function(response) {
     response.json();
   })
   .then(function(messages) {
     this.messageView.wrapInHTML(messages);
   })
   .then(function(wrappedMessages) {
     document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML(wrappedMessages);
   });
}
```

While I want to have something like this:

```
// in messageModel.js

MessageModel.prototype.fetchMessages = function() {
 fetch('https://example-api.com/messages')
   .then(function(response) {
     response.json();
   })


// in messageController.js

function showMessages() {
  messageData = this.messageModel.fetchMessages();
  wrappedMessages = this.messageView.wrapInHTML(messages);
  document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML(wrappedMessages);
}
```

Comment: You can't get around the asynchronous nature of this problem. You can use `async/await` to make it look a little more synchronous, but it only makes it appear that way. You can also return the promise generated by `fetch` which would allow you to process stuff in `showMessages()`.

Comment: same as "Is there a way to open the package now *(and use its content)*, that amazon will deliver next week?"

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your answers. I'm currently on a course and they suggested we use fetch but the requirements for the app include using the MVC pattern and maintaining the single responsibility principle. Seems like that's not really possible with fetch.

Answer (score 0):

## Semi-Solution

Albeit hacky and maybe a counter-pattern. You could preload that data on the page with synchronous requests, using:

```
head
  script(id='jsonData_1', type='application/json', src="/foo/bar/json")
  // Other JS/Imports etc
```

Or use `document.write` and load the JSON like:

```
head
  script.
    document.write('\x3Cscript type="application/json" src="/foo/bar/j.json">\x3C/script>');
```

***Note:*** HTML is written in PUG / HAML for readability

In your code itself read the DOM for that data, like:

```
const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('#jsonData_1').innerHTML)
```

### Final Thoughts

Again, please don't do this. But there is a way ;)